# How does overloading lambdas by using user-defined deduction guides work?

Tags: c++, c++17

When I was reading [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0847r2.html), I saw lambdas being overloaded in the [Recursive Lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0847r2.html#recursive-lambdas) section.  I was confused as I've never saw that before and I thought it might be a new keyword in C++ that I didn't hear about before.

Turns out, it is not a keyword, but a helper function/class that just wasn't defined in the paper.  I finally found some information on it on cppreference.com [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) page.

In the example provided, I understood everything that was happening except for one thing:

```
// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
...
int main() {
...
        // 4. another type-matching visitor: a class with 3 overloaded operator()'s
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
            [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; },
        }, v);
}
```

As I understand it, using braces (`overloaded{...}`) would indicate that the constructor is being called, but there isn't one, and even if it had called the `overloaded` function, it has no body.

So, my question is: What's happening here?  I found some reference that it is using user-defined deduction guides, but I'm still not clear.

## EDIT

The crux of this, is my misinterpretation of:

```
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

This is not a free template function declaration, but a (tl;dr) [user-defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), which states what the default template class parameters should be for the constructor.

This is only barely tangentially related to [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special), which is what this question was marked as a duplicate of, and is only briefly mentioned in an answer entitled [What will change for C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53819762/1366368).

Comment: Since you are familiar with cppreference.com, search it for the following keywords: "aggregate initialization" and "uniform initialization syntax". This is a clever combination of using deduction guides together with aggregate initialization.

Comment: Try reading [this article](https://dev.to/tmr232/that-overloaded-trick-overloading-lambdas-in-c17); it may help.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: The correct term is "list initialization".

Comment: Thanks @ravnsgaard, I already read that, and it's not helped.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I don't think that this question that you posted is a duplication of this one.  I understand what an aggregate is, as well as what *"list initialization"* is.  However, this syntax is strange. I guess that aggregate initialization can be happening on the base types, in the order that they appear, and that the `overloaded` helper function seems to be generating the type, but the helper function has no body, and I would have expected the call to the helper function to be `overloaded(...)` or even `overloaded({...})` neither of which work.  This is what my question is about.

Comment: @Adrian `overloaded` is not a helper function, it's a struct. The second line is the deduction guide the type is deduced from the types of the parameters passed to the constructor.

Comment: @super, ah, of course. Now I understand! I had the answer. I just didn't go far enough in my research. Thanks.